# Shift a column based on id and time sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big table like below:

```
id  date    count
1   201241  1
2   201241  2
3   201241  0
1   201242  5
2   201242  3
4   201242  4
3   201243  8
4   201243  2
...
```

How can I shift count column based on id and date columns.

```
id  date    shifted_count
1   201241  0
2   201241  0
3   201241  0
1   201242  1
2   201242  2
4   201242  0
3   201243  0
4   201243  4
...
```

I had some tries but they are incorrect:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT count OVER(ORDER BY id , date ASC) shcount
    FROM mytable
)
UPDATE mytable SET shifted_count = (SELECT shcount from CTE )
```

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: shift by (id and date) simultaneously. date has an order which shows week of year